# Python Packet Sniffer : Fetch website URL from IP addresses

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, packet-sniffers

The code shown below (Packet Sniffer) :

Works on the principle that a raw socket is capable of receiving all incoming traffic in Linux.

Upon running, it outputs (*or sniffs)* all the IP addresses accessed by the system.

Here's the code :

```
#Packet sniffer in python for Linux
#Sniffs only incoming TCP packet

import socket, sys
from struct import *

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# receive a packet
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #take first 20 characters for the ip header
    ip_header = packet[0:20]

    #now unpack them :)
    iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

    version_ihl = iph[0]
    version = version_ihl >> 4
    ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

    iph_length = ihl * 4

    ttl = iph[5]
    protocol = iph[6]
    s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
    d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

    print 'Version : ' + str(version) + ' IP Header Length : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protocol : ' + str(protocol) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)

    tcp_header = packet[iph_length:iph_length+20]

    #now unpack them :)
    tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

    source_port = tcph[0]
    dest_port = tcph[1]
    sequence = tcph[2]
    acknowledgement = tcph[3]
    doff_reserved = tcph[4]
    tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4

    print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Sequence Number : ' + str(sequence) + ' Acknowledgement : ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' TCP header length : ' + str(tcph_length)

    h_size = iph_length + tcph_length * 4
    data_size = len(packet) - h_size

    #get data from the packet
    data = packet[h_size:]

    print 'Data : ' + data
    print
```

[Here is the Source (with explanation)](http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/)

[Sample Output of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2JBb.png)

Variables (in my concern) have the following meaning:

> s_addr : source IP
>
> d_addr : destination IP - which is always IP of my system

**Query:** Is there a way in which I can get to know the Website URL accessed by the system ?

**If answer is NO,** Then what can be done in the given code to get more details about the content being accessed?

I am making a project in python in which server can sniff all the packets arriving at client's system.

I want something more than just IP addresses.

I am fully aware of the software *Wireshark*. But I am trying to do all this with the help of raw sockets and python script.

Comment: You need to parse the data and see if it contains an HTTP request. The URL pathname will be in the parameter to the `GET` or `POST` request, the hostname will be in the `Host:` header line.

Comment: And remember that this will only be in the first data packet sent from the client to the server. You can't do it when you're processing the `SYN` packets that open the connection.

Comment: Related: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ and [tag:scapy].